# Find duplicate in an array, populate second array with highest recurring number of duplicates in java

Tags: java, arrays

So this is my first post and I'm fairly new to coding. I am populating an array with 5 random integers. I then want to iterate through that array and find any duplicates, storing the duplicate integers that occurs most often in a new array. So essentially if the random generate integers were say, [6,2,2,1,1] i would expect that the second method should loop and create a new array with two integers both with a value of 2 or [2,2].

```
private int min = 1;
private int max = 6;

private int[] randArray = new int[5];
private int num1;
private int num2;
private int num3;
private int num4;
private int num5;
private int num6;
private int[] maxFreqArray = new int[6];

public int[] fillRandArray() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
        randArray[i] = random.nextInt(max) + min;
    }
    return randArray;
}

public int[] fillMaxFreqArray() {
    for (int i = 1; i < maxFreqArray.length; i++) {
        if (randArray[i] == 1) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num1++;
        } else if (randArray[i] == 2) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num2++;
        } else if (randArray[i] == 3) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num3++;
        } else if (randArray[i] == 4) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num4++;
        } else if (randArray[i] == 5) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num5++;
        } else if (randArray[i] == 6) {
            maxFreqArray[i] = num6++;
        } 

    }

    return maxFreqArray;
}
```

My problem is two fold, first it appears I am populating the maxFreqArray with only 5 integers as when I print the array I get random value of [0, 2, 1, 1, 3] or something similar but never anything greater than 3. Any ideas?

Comment: In java arrays start at zero index

Comment: Check Map in java collections. It might give you some idea about counting array elements frequency.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, setting index to zero did produce value higher than 3. But resulted in values over the max.

Comment: To get numbers in range from `min` to `max` including, use the formula `random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min`. Also, you get 5 integers because you declare `private int[] randArray = new int[5];`, if you want to have 6 numbers, just declare `private int[] randArray = new int[6];`. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 6, 2, 2, 1, 1 ,1 };

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (map.get(a[i]) != null) {
                map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(a[i], 1);
            }
        }

        int maxvalue = 0, respectiveKey = 0;
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() >= maxvalue) {
                maxvalue = entry.getValue();
                respectiveKey = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        int[] newarra = new int[maxvalue];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxvalue; i++) {
            newarra[i] = respectiveKey;
        }

//      return newarra;

    }
```

This is solution is in java 5, If you are familiar with java 7 and 8 onwards you can use stream operation to achieve the same.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to write out the Java, but the algorithm I would use is as follows, assuming random numbers are integers >= 0:

```
resArr = new array<int>(<max of range + 1>)
// i.e. if random numbers are in 1-6, max of range is 7
// array is initialized to default values (0)
// [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in randomNumberArray // [6,2,2,1,1]
  resArr[randomNumberArray[i]]++
  // use value of random number to index into res array and increment count

// now have a res array that looks like [0,2,2,0,0,0,1]

maxCount = 0
maxIndex = 0
for i in resArr
  if resArr[i] >= maxCount
    maxIndex = i
    // each time resArr has a count >= equal to
    // the current max count, grab that index
    // since we want the highest matching duplicate

return maxIndex
// maxIndex is the value from the random array
// i.e. 2 for this example
```

This uses a temp array to hold the counts of numbers seen in the random array, the index being the value from the random array. One O(n) pass over the random number array, and one O(range) pass over the result array to compute the max count seen.

Answer (score 0):

To get random numbers in range `[min, max]` inclusive:

```
int random(int min, int max) {
  return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

So, in `fillRandArray` you can use `randArray[i] = random(min, max);`

Also, you actually declare `private int[] randArray = new int[5];`. So, that's why you always get `randArray` of size 5.

The formula above should be applied because `random.nextInt(bound)` returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between `0` (inclusive) and the specified `bound` (exclusive). So:

- Minimum value returned by `random.nextInt(bound)` is `0`. By using either `random.nextInt(max) + min` or `random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min` you'll get `min` value as result.
- Maximum value returned by `random.nextInt(bound)` is `bound - 1`. By using formula `random.nextInt(max)` you'll actually get max possible value `max - 1 + min`. Because of this, you should use `random.nextInt((max - min) + 1)`, so at bound case you'll get `(max - min) + min`, which is equal to `max`.